# Virtual column with calculation in Vaex

Tags: python, dataframe, vaex

I want to set a virtual column to a calculation using another column in Vaex. I need to use an if statement inside this calculation. In general I want to call

```
df['calculation_col'] = log(df['original_col']) if df['original_col'] == 0 else -4
```

I then try to run the count function in Vaex:

```
hist = df.count(
        binby='calculation_col',
        limits=limits,
        shape=binnum,
        delay=True
    )
```

When I try to execute this code I get the error `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`.

How can I use a conditional for a virtual column in Vaex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most "vaex" way to do this would be to use `where`:

```py
import vaex
df = vaex.example()
# The syntax is where(condition, if satisfied, else)
df['calculated_col'] = df.func.where(df['x'] < 10, 0, -4)
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to use a mask for subsetting the relevant rows:

```py
import vaex

df = vaex.example()

mask = df["id"] < 10

df["new_col"] = mask * df["x"] + ~mask * (-4)

print(df[['id', 'x', 'new_col']].head(4))
# #    id          x    new_col
# 0     0   1.23187     1.23187
# 1    23  -0.163701   -4
# 2    32  -2.12026    -4
# 3     8   4.71559     4.71559
```

Kindly note that in the original script, there would be an error triggered by `numpy` due to taking `np.log` of zero, so using `np.log1p` might more be appropriate in that case.